# Utilizar librería jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

estoy intentando utilizar la librería de jsPDF y no hay manera de hacerla funcionar.
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js
He probado con algunas versiones anteriores y sí me funciona pero necesito que sea la última versión ya que se han implementado cosas como poder importar una fuente.ttf directamente mediante la ruta.

Todo el rato me sale el error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined"

```js
var doc = new jsPDF({
    orientation: "landscape,
    unit: 'mm',
    format: [65,85]
})
doc.addFont("/fonts/Pompiere-Regular.ttf", "Pompiere", "regular");
doc.setFont("Pompiere");
doc.setFontType("regular");

doc.text("test", 10, 10, "center")

doc.save("test.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi no me da error si hago el import antes de este modo:

```
import { jsPDF } from "./jspdf";
```

Por otro parte, en tu código tienes un error tipográfico pues no cierras las comillas despues de `"landscape`.

Aquí el ejemplo completo sin errores (aquí da otro error, pero es por otros motivos, pruébalo en tu sitio a ver):

```js
import { jsPDF } from "./jspdf";

var doc = new jsPDF({
    orientation: "landscape",
    unit: 'mm',
    format: [65,85]
})

doc.addFont("/fonts/Pompiere-Regular.ttf", "Pompiere", "regular");
doc.setFont("Pompiere");
doc.setFontType("regular");

doc.text("test", 10, 10, "center")

doc.save("test.pdf");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No me deja hacer el import... me dice lo siguiente: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module "

Comment: Pues a pelo si que funciona sin mostrar ese error (https://jsfiddle.net/qfx2s0y3/).  Si estas usando node o algo similar deberias decirlo en la pregunta. Si es así prueba con `<script type="module" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>`

Comment: No... no utilizo ningún framework. A mi en el link que me has pasado también me aparece un error.

Comment: Pues a mi no ... Es decir, si le doy al Run tal cual no aparece ningun error en consola.  Si haces otra cosa para forzar el error dime cual es.